# razor used followed by a word

Tags: 2013, razormediator

I'm using razor in Tridion 2013. 
I have this, and the number must be dynamic

```
<span class="stars stars5"></span>
```

I've tried:

```
<span class="stars stars@Metadata.stars.Description"></span>
```

But doesn't work... 
But if I have a space between stars and `@Metadata.stars` it works

```
<span class="stars stars @Metadata.stars.Description"></span>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
<text>stars:</text>@Metadata.stars
```

Read more here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx